# Information about Ports opened by SparkJava running on top Jetty server

Tags: java, embedded-jetty, spark-java

I am investigating the ports used by JavaSpark (Running JettyServer internally)
I noticed there are some random ports (Between 40000-60000) opened and connected to eachother within the same process.

See the following screenshot from tcpview:

[image: Screenshot of ports from tcpview]

Can anyone provide information about why those ports are used?
I noticed there is no communication between them.
I will be very happy if you could give me any info about them.

Comment: Does JMX (via jmc console) reveal anything useful about the specific components in your java stack that have those ports bound?

Comment: They are there even when i dont use JMX. My guess is that they are used by embedded-jetty server of JavaSpark framework. They are randomly opened ports (First available port given by OS) but why jetty uses them?

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that jmx is using those ports, just use the 'jmc' gui (ships with java) and check the MBeans on the process, there _might_ be a few entries that will hint at an open/bound port.  Those entries should give you context on what component in your java stack is opening those ports/connections.

Comment: I tried to check them with jmc, but it does not shows those ports